# Rails 3 - Use only OpenID authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, openid, google-openid

I want to add authentication to my Ruby on Rails 3 app, but I only need users to be able to authenticate using their Google accounts, because I'm making it a hosted app for the Chrome Webstore, so I think OpenID would work well for this. I want to have some custom fields in the user database to store user-specific data. What should I use for this? I want users to be able to sign up only with OpenID.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try omniauth gem, it uses not only Google OpenID. Omniauth takes user's data from provider and pass to your application which is you can amplify

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) and [authlogic-oid](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_openid) add-on to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [devise_openid_authenticatable](https://github.com/nbudin/devise_openid_authenticatable) gem. I haven't used it myself but it looks like it would do what you want using the [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) authentication gem, which is what I use on all of my Rails projects.